# How to make an Email Field in form.py a required field?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I have been trying several methods but cant seem to make it work.

Here are my codes:

```
 class Meta:
        model = User
        # set fields to be used in registration form
        fields = ['username','email','password','password2']

    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=100) <---
    password= forms.PasswordInput()
    password2=forms.PasswordInput()


# user email must be unique
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    # check if account with email exists
    if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Email address already exists')
    return email
```

Does anyone know why the required=True does not work to make it as a required field?

Comment: You should call the `super()` to check the inherited validation, which will validate the `required=True`.

Answer (score 0):

What `@WillemVanOnsem` said in his comment to your question, I'll expand it here to make it clearer: you should call `super().clean_email()` to assure that all default validations of that field are run.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = super().clean_email()

    if email is not None:
        # check if account with email exists
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email address already exists.')

    return email
```